# iPhone equivalent of Android's SavedPreferences

Tags: iphone, android, persistence

I'm writing an app for the iPhone that I've already created in Android and Blackberry and was hoping that there was an equivalent for SavedPreferences in iOS.  Specifically I'm looking for the functionality to be able to create favorites on the fly.  So in Android I can save a string into SavedPreferences with the identifier of "server project favorites".  Is there something similar I can do in iOS without bothering with a SQL database for simple strings?

Comment: If it is nothing that sensitive, I do suggest `NSUserDefaults`. But for usernames/passwords I strongly suggest NOT using `NSUserDefaults`. I cannot tell you how many times I have found API keys, Admin Usernames, Passwords and more by browsing through application files on my iPod :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/) is what you are looking for.

Example with an array for *server project favorites*:

```
// Saving
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray *favorites = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Favorite 1", @"Favorite 2", nil];
[defaults setObject:favorites forKey:@"favorites"];

// Retrieving
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray *favorites = [defaults arrayForKey:@"favorites"];
```

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)